# Set ls -l time format

Tags: ls, date, alias, time

I would like for all my `ls` commands that display a date, such as `ls -l`, to print the date column in a format of my choosing. Currently, I manually set this every time with `--time-style`. Is there any way of permanently setting this to, say, `long-iso` (as opposed to issuing `ls -l --time-style="long-iso"` on every invocation)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you define an alias such as:

```bash
alias ls='ls --time-style=long-iso'
```

then all `ls` invocations which end up displaying dates will use that.

Comment: I added this line to my `.bashrc` file, however, my colors have now disappeared! I'm guessing that this command is overwriting previous color options set to ls. Is there a way of telling the shell to simply *append* the `--time-style` option to the ls command?

Comment: Check out http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124505 for various ways of stacking alias definitions; one of those should allow you to add `--time-style=long-iso` to your existing `ls` alias.

Answer (score 12):

This question is similar to [the one asked on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/268721/how-to-make-ls-produce-iso-8601-format), so I'll repeat [the answer I put there](https://askubuntu.com/a/465257/11952):

```bash
export TIME_STYLE=<desired_time_style>
```

So, if you want all invocation of `ls` to produce output with `--time-style=long-iso`, you do:

```bash
export TIME_STYLE=long-iso
```

This method works on Ubuntu and Cygwin, and will likely work with all `ls` that comes from **[GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html)** (Mac OS X will need to install gnu coreutils using `brew`).

Comment: Actually good answer considered the info about the necessity of GNU coreutils. Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

May I suggest some rudimentary aliases:

```bash
# - escape potentially existing alias
# - use colors when appropriate
# - group directories first
alias ls='\ls --color=auto --group-directories-first'

# - long list `ls`
# - human readable sizes
# - ommit hidden items
# - show sizes in kibibytes
# - set date format to a template of yyyy-mmm-dd, e.g. 2022-Mar-06
alias ll="ls -lhk --time-style='+%Y-%b-%d'"
```

For Bash, just put these lines into `.bash_aliases` file which should be sourced by your `.bashrc`, just in case it does not:

```bash
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

---

Further info on formatting for the GNU `coreutils`:

- [Date conversion specifiers](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Date-conversion-specifiers.html)
- [Time conversion specifiers](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Time-conversion-specifiers.html)