# How to set ls -lh with time and long date format in descending order in .bashrc

Tags: ls, date, sort

I tried setting the following alias in .bashrc -

```
$ alias ll
alias ll='ls --color=auto --time-style=long-iso'
```

But the above doesn't work. I want to have the long-iso as well as descending order (date or/and time-wise) whenever I ask it to list files in CLI. Is there anyway to do that ?

The above command does give me color output but not long-iso part. Am I doing something wrong ?

I did see [Set ls -l time format](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/275728/set-ls-l-time-format) but doesn't help in my case :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are missing a `-l` to turn on the long listing format and `-t` to sort by modification time.

Do:

```
alias ll='ls -lt --color=auto --time-style=long-iso'
```

To include hidden files too:

```
alias ll='ls -alt --color=auto --time-style=long-iso'
```

To reverse the order of sorting, oldest first, add `-r`:

```
alias ll='ls -ltr --color=auto --time-style=long-iso'
alias ll='ls -altr --color=auto --time-style=long-iso'
```

Comment: That works but doesn't have any descending order in listing of files wth respect to the date and time. Is there a way to do that as well ?

Comment: @shirish Check my edits

Comment: You also need `-t` to order by last modification time.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Was into that, but Gilles incorporated that already.

Comment: @Giles and @heemayi - a mistake, both seem to have -r , the first one one should not have 'r' in the flag ` -lt`

Comment: @shirish Which one are you talking about? The first one is `alias ll='ls -lt --color=auto --time-style=long-iso'` which doesn't have `-r`

Comment: ah, sorry I was thinking it is the last ones.  I also actually added h so it's `-alth` at my end but gives what I need the most, thank you again.

Comment: @shirish `-h` makes the file size human readable, that's all.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to passing `--time-style` to `ls` is to set the `TIME_STYLE` environment variable.

e.g. in `.bashrc`

```
export TIME_STYLE=long-iso
```

Documented in [coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Formatting-file-timestamps.html).